# Executing a local file from an intranet Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, local, intranet

I am creating a Flex application for intranet use.

I need the application to execute files, with different file types (txt, emails, etc.) at specific known locations on the clients computer.

Is it possible to give permissions to the Flex application to execute local files? (I have administrative rights on the clients computer)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute or access if your Flex application is running in the browser. However in your case I suggest to use the AIR platform and in this case you can run a native file (take a look on NativeProcess api) - of course is the one using the Flex app has operating system rights to access/execute the files.

Comment: That would work, but I need the Flex application to be embedded in a website, something I can't do with AIR.

I think my only possible solution is to install on the client a service that lets me execute files, and to connect to that service with Flex.